# Binding date value to Angular Kendo Date Picker Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I have an API which returns the date in this format `2018-12-24T16:00:00.000Z` (ISO string). I am using Angular, Kendo UI and Typescript.

The problem that I am facing is the date is not getting bound to the Kendo date picker. I have read the documentation to integrate with JSON but I failed to apply it to my circumstances. And most of the solution in the Google use Javascript.

API call

```
"valueJson": {
    "startDate": "2018-12-24T16:00:00.000Z"
}
```

component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private service: PromotionsService, ) {
    this.date = new Date();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      code: ["", [Validators.required]],
      name: "Please Select",
      customFieldDtoList: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          paramName: "details",
          valueJson: this.fb.group({
            category: "Please Select",
            startDate: this.date,
            endDate: this.date,
            values: 0
          }),
          updatedDate: this.date
        })
      ])
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<div class="col-6" formArrayName='customFieldDtoList'>
          <div formGroupName=0>
          <div formGroupName="valueJson">
            <p>Start Date</p>
            <kendo-datepicker formControlName="startDate" style="width: 100%;" ></kendo-datepicker>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Upon using `{{ myForm.value | json }}` ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J18j.png)) to see the data, the `2018-12-24T16:00:00.000Z` value can be displayed, however is not displayable by the date picker.

How do I change this ISO string and make it readable by the date picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I managed to solve this somehow. In order to convert ISO string to JS object, you just need to use IntlService `parseDate` it in the pipe subscribe in your **initializeForm** NOT in your **ngOnInit**. Here is an example on how I do it:

```
initializeForm() {
this.service
  .getspecificPromotion(this.id)
  .pipe(map(x => x.data))
  .subscribe(resp => {
    const {
      customFieldDtoList: [
        {
          valueJson: {
            startDate,
            endDate,
          }
        }
      ]
    } = resp;

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      customFieldDtoList: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          valueJson: this.fb.group({
            category: category,
            startDate: this.intl.parseDate(startDate),
            endDate: this.intl.parseDate(endDate),
          })
        })
      ])
    });
}
```

And don't forget to import:

```
import { IntlService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
```

And add them in your constructor:

```
constructor(
    private service: PromotionsService,
    private intl: IntlService
  ) {}
```

By doing this, your date formatting in Kendo Grid will also work too.

Documentation: [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/integration-with-json/)